# std::Vector push_back time for first element significantly greater than subsequent elements

Tags: c++, vector

I have created a vector of integers. I find that the time taken for first push_back is significantly greater than the subsequent push_back. Why is it so. To avoid reallocation I have reserved the size of vector.

```
std::vector<int> myList;
myList.reserve(10);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  myList.push_back(rand() % 100);
}
```

The timings obtained for push_back (in nanoseconds) are as follows. I am compiling the program with `-O3` flag on.

```
1536
166
124
127
119
125
127
125
126
127
```

Could someone please explain the huge difference of `10` times.

Comment: First guess: cache. Also, show your timing code.

Comment: The timing code function is as follows: timespec t; counter = t.tv_sec * 1000000000 + t.tv_nsec

Comment: Perhaps the vector's heap space isn't allocated until it's first required.

Comment: @T.C.: Could you please explain the concept of `caching` here.

Comment: @RichardForrest: The same thing is observed when I replace vector with an array. I am not able to understand the behaviour.

Comment: Locality of reference?

Comment: I mean, show exactly the code you are running to generate the timing you are reporting. I should be able to copy-paste it into an online compiler and get similar numbers.

Comment: @bhavesh The same thing is *not* seen when using a `std::array`, as that class has no `push_back` nor `reserve` methods. Out of curiosity, What happens when you take the `rand()` out ? (may as well trim to minimal).

Comment: It's probably just cpu caching. Before you push an element into the vector the cpu doesn't know where in memory you want to access next. When you push the first element, the cpu learns this new address and keeps it in it's cache in case another element will be added nearby. It's just common sense.

Comment: Reason why I asked about eliminating `rand()` : Without `rand()`, [see **here**](http://ideone.com/5abS8q). With `rand()`, [see **here**](http://ideone.com/0oE5vU). With a seeded `rand()` via `srand()`, [see **here**](http://ideone.com/Dh2rv4). Finally, default seeding, but with a primer that invokes `rand()` once prior to the timing loop, [see **here**](http://ideone.com/JaWu86). There are a ton of things contributing to the timings in this.